# How to mock SqlQuery

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

I'm new in writing tests and Mock. I'm trying to figure it out how to mock Raw SQL to retrieve data. Here's what I have:

I have DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() 
         : base("Main")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DbBook> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DbMovie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

I have controller BooksController.cs

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    private readonly BookDataContext _db;
    public BooksController ()
    {
        _db = new BookDataContext();
    }

    public BooksController (BookDataContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("books")]
    public Book GetBooks()
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var test = _db.Books.SqlQuery("select * from BOOK");
            var test2 = from b in _db.Books
                            orderby b.Books
                            select b;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have test

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetBook()
{
    var data = new List<DbBook>
    {
        new DbBook{ Book = "Book1"},
        new DbBook{ Book = "Book2"}
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<DbScriptId>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<DbBook>>().Setup(m => 
    m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<DbBook>>().Setup(m => 
    m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<DbBook>>().Setup(m => 
    m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<DbBook>>().Setup(m => 
    m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
    mockSet.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
         .Returns<object[]>(sc => data.SingleOrDefault());


    var mockContext = new Mock<DataContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Books).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var controller = new BooksController (mockContext.Object);
    var books = controller.GetBook();
}
```

I can retrieve data using Linq (test2) but using SqlQuery I always get null (test). How to change that using SqlQuery I get same result as using Linq? Also I'm getting to know that creating InMemory database actually creates some lists (type=IQueriable) in background, not database. Can you please provide some explanation and resolution for this issue?

Comment: What are you mocking? Raw SQL takes away all dependency injection and leaves you with nothing to mock. What are you trying to test?

Comment: I should edit code. I just want to test if I get some results from GetBooks() method. When I debug test it jumps into GetBooks() method, then "test" variable gets null meanwhile "test2" gets required data. Ok, how to test Raw SQL statement?

Answer (score 3):

How about this. (not sure if I understand your question right)

```
 var queryMock = new Mock<DbSqlQuery<DbBook>>();
 queryMock.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

 mockSet.Setup(m => m.SqlQuery(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(queryMock.Object);
```

This example assumes that all queries will return all items.

Comment: I've tried and looks better, "test" returns an object but Results view returns "Enumeration yielded no results" while "test2" (Linq) normally does. But it's step forward, I guess I just need some extra knowledge to get this thing done. Thanks